# Validate if record is the root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have the following self nested parent/children model

```
class Vmt::EvaluationUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: "Vmt::EvaluationUnit", foreign_key: :evaluation_unit_id, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Vmt::EvaluationUnit", foreign_key: :evaluation_unit_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, reject_if: :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

  validates :evaluation_name, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |e| e.parent.nil? }
end
```

But the validation rule for :evaluation_name doesn't work when I try to **create** a new top-level unit with children. Here is the log entry of the Create-Request with one child:

```
Started POST "/vmt/evaluation_units" for 192.168.0.117 at 2015-08-20 10:36:39 +0200
Processing by Vmt::EvaluationUnitsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xQjGeIr/I+iPi+KG+0SLIH06JzIbOd8synWtvb1+ksY=", "vmt_evaluation_unit"=>{"evaluation_name"=>"Neu", "name"=>"Gesamt", "max_point"=>"200", "children_attributes"=>{"1440059791662"=>{"name"=>"Neu1", "max_point"=>"200", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Speichern"}
BEGIN
ROLLBACK
```

It seems, that the parent isn't set for children neither when the validation is happening. How can I validate, that the :evaluation_name is present when the record has no parent?

Comment: Try adding `inverse_of` option to your associations.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you!